# Google sheets key sensitive search bar?

Tags: google-sheets, uppercase, lowercase, searchbar

I have duplicated a browser tab and I have implemented a search bar to filter only the row for the word I am looking for... however, if I don't write the exact word (lower or upper case) nothing will show up...

The formula I am using is `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1xxxxx8RviacxxxxxOWXx_xxxxrEi-xxxxDi_xx","Roster!B3:I"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col2 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col3 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col4 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col5 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col6 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col7 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' or Col8 CONTAINS '"&G1&"' ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try wrapping the matching columns/cell within lower to avoid this mismatch.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({to_text(IMPORTRANGE("1xxxxx8RviacxxxxxOWXx_xxxxrEi-xxxxDi_xx","Roster!B3:I"))},"SELECT * WHERE lower(Col1) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col2) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col3) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col4) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col5) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col6) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col7) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' or lower(Col8) CONTAINS '"&lower(G1)&"' "))`

-

[image]

Alternate Formula:

```
=filter({B3:I},REGEXMATCH(BYROW(B3:I,LAMBDA(bix,TEXTJOIN("|",1,bix))),"(?i)"&G1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH(FLATEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(x),,9^9)), "\b"&G1&"\b")))
 (IMPORTRANGE("1xxxxx8RviacxxxxxOWXx_xxxxrEi-xxxxDi_xx", "Roster!B3:I"))
```

or insensitive:

```
=LAMBDA(x, FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH(FLATEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(x),,9^9)), "(?i)\b"&G1&"\b")))
 (IMPORTRANGE("1xxxxx8RviacxxxxxOWXx_xxxxrEi-xxxxDi_xx", "Roster!B3:I"))
```